Some data missing after migrating to new Cassandra cluster nodes
I need one help!
Our current Cassandra version is 3.11.6, we want to migrate to new Cassandra cluster nodes having version 4.0.13.

We took the snapshot of the one of our database from current 6 nodes.
We created tables and schemas for all the tables in new cassandra 6 nodes.
Restored the snapshots in their respective new cassandra nodes.
Ran sshupgrade.
Ran nodetool repair on each nodes one at a time (Our cassandra version is 4.x, so by default it will perform incremental repair)
We ran nodetool repair -vd and verified that all nodes are in sync.
But when we did the count, its not matching. For example for one of the tables, the count in current cassandra node was showing 140k
while in new cassandra nodes, it was showing 85k. We checked for couple of tables and data mismatch was there for all of them.

We tried running full repair instead of incremental repair in step 5.
We checked both debug logs and system logs but we didn't find anything specific which can indicate a problem.
We tried copying all the .db files from the existing node and copied it to new nodes and followed the same steps again (Steps 4 - 6).
We tried to run nodetool rebuild (even though its seems irrelevant)
We compared the configuration of existing node with new nodes and its same.
Any suggestion on what can we do further?

So something you could try, would be to upgrade the current 3.11.6 cluster to 4.0.13. Then, (wipe) and join the new 4.0.13 nodes to that cluster as a new, logical data center. Run a nodetool rebuild on each of the new nodes, and they should be all-set.

Thanks @Aoron. We identified the problem. Token ranges were defined in the configuration file in the existing nodes. We defined the same token ranges for the new nodes and it worked fine. We copied the snapshot and located it to the data folder. After which we restarted the nodes and ran ssupgrade command. This fixed the problem.
We didnt run nodetool import. What I am thinking is because of the fact that we had token ranges defined in config file, Cassandra automatically loads the data from the path and it doesnt require to run nodetool import command.
